# Trouble parsing a text file

Tags: c, parsing

I'm currently trying to pick out specific parts of a text file, specifically classes out of a course catalog that also contains unneeded text.  I need to get the course number, description, credit hours, and professor. First time posting on here, so sorry for any format problems:

```
void readFile(FILE* input, data** head){
 char* line = (char*)(malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_LINE));
 int x, y, k;
 y = k = 0;
 data* temp1 = (data*)(malloc(sizeof(data)));
 temp1->next = NULL;
 //get line

 while(fgets(line, MAX_LINE, input)){
  line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0';
  char* token = strtok(line, "\t");

  while(token != NULL){
   //determine if token is a number, descriptor, etc.
   x = dataT(token, k); //function return int value 1-4 depending on data type found, 0 for garbage

   if(x == 1){
    k = 1; //used to signal if coming after a course number for other data types
    strcpy(temp1->cnum, token);
    y++;
   }

   //etc for rest of types...
   //....
   //load found tokens once four have been found(file will always have one of each before repeating a type)

   if(y == 4){
    loadList(*head, (temp1->cnum), (temp1->cdesc), (temp1->hours), (temp1->cprof));
    y = 0;
    k = 0;
   }
   token = strtok(NULL, "\t");
  }
 }
```

Finally, an example of some input from the file (parts I need are marked, no asterisks in actual file):

```
**COSC-010**  **INTRO TO COMPUTER SCIENCE**          **3**
  available seating
  01  LEC T 1:15-2:30 REI 112          **Miles A**
      LAB M 4:15-5:30 STM 343
     CROSS LIST: COSC-501-01
      MSB STUDENTS ONLY
     SPRING ONLY COURSE
```

I will provide more info on request.

Comment: So, what is the question, i.e., what are you having trouble with?

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem.

Comment: It won't load the file data into a linked list. I really just need some advice to point me in the right direction; is this the right way to go about it?  Is there a resource I missed that could help?

Comment: perhaps printing out the tokens as they are returned from `strtok()` will shed some light.  Also is your input data tab delimited vs space, you don't mention the format of your input file?  If it is space or tab, than change your `strtok(blah, "\t")` to `strtok(blah, " \t")`.

Comment: You need to use a debugger, and find what is the problem exactly. Then you will be able to ask more precise questions if you still can not solve the problem.

Comment: Ok, the problem is my dataT function, it only returns 0 every time.  Will work on fixing, thank you.